# How to show Search charm when user starts typing in windows 8 app (html & js)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Building a Win8 app using JS and Html.  How can I have the Search charm appear as soon as the user starts typing when my app is open?  I have the following code in `default.js`, just before `app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {`:

```
var searchPane = Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView();
var showOnKeyboardInput = searchPane.showOnKeyboardInput;
searchPane.showOnKeyboardInput = showOnKeyboardInput;
```

When I try that, and I start typing when the app is open, nothing happens. Do I need that snippet on each js file that I have?  I have a home.js and a detail.js (multi-page app).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This retrieves the setting value:

```
var showOnKeyboardInput = searchPane.showOnKeyboardInput;
```

This re-assigns the same value to the setting:

```
searchPane.showOnKeyboardInput = showOnKeyboardInput;
```

So it is normal that nothing changes. Try:

```
searchPane.showOnKeyboardInput = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.search.searchpane.showonkeyboardinput.aspx) for this shows searchPane.showOnKeyboardInput = showOnKeyboardInput for the JavaScript syntax example so I can see how this would cause some confusion.